# Prevent an open terminal from being closed

Tags: command-line, 20.04, ubuntu-mate

It has been a long time, so I am rusty with my commands.

I use a script to have reminders. One I have running will display "Meteor shower occurs after midnight." after 3 hours.

Is there a way to prevent me from accidentally closing a terminal which has my timer script running?

**Update:**

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  Sound alarm after specifying time and message 
# Must input time delay AND message in double quotes !!
#
#       
# ** sleep can also accept intergers ex. sleep 7.63
# Made alias for it type al 

    # Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select commands, 
    # and arithmetic for commands and their # arguments or associated word lists after they are expanded 
    # and before they are executed. The value of the PS4 variable is # expanded and the resultant value is printed before the # command and its expanded arguments.

Red='\e[0;31m'     
BRed='\e[1;31m' 
BIRed='\e[1;91m' # ${BIRed} this works
Gre='\e[0;32m'     
BGre='\e[1;32m'
BBlu='\e[1;34m' # ${BBlu}
BWhi='\e[1;37m'
Black='\e[0;30' 
BWhite='\e[0m 1;37'
# This defines a variable containing the ANSI escape sequence to clear
# the effect of all previous ANSI escape sequences that define formatting (colors, underlining, etc).
RCol='\e[0m'; 

            

soundfile="/usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Alarm_Clock_Sound.mp3"

clear
amixer -D pulse sset Master 40% > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ -f "$soundfile" ];
then
     echo -e "${BGre}Soundfile is present."
else
      
  echo "File $soundfile does NOT exist."
  echo
  echo "Program will now exit."
  exit
fi

[ -z "$2" ] && {
echo 
echo -e " ${BIRed}Error!! No time value given and/or message specified !!"
echo
echo -e "   ${BBlu}Alarm Program 2018 ${RCol}"
echo
echo -e "   alarm.sh [time value in seconds] Message in double Quotes"; 
echo -e "   alarm 5m   = 5 minute alarm"
echo -e "   alarm 5h   = 5 hour alarm"
echo -e "   alarm 5d   = 5 day alarm"
echo -e "   alarm 1.5m = 1 minute 30 seconds alarm"
echo 
echo -e "   alarm.sh 1m "\"Take bread out of oven."\""  

echo 
exit 1; }
echo  -e "\033[32;5mTIMER COUNTING DOWN to $1 \033[0m"
sleep $1
{
    for ((volume = 15; volume <= 35; volume += 2)); do
        # 2> /dev/null suppresses messages for amixer AND (c)vlc
        amixer -D pulse sset Master ${volume}% > /dev/null
        sleep .5
    done
} &

mpg123 $soundfile > /dev/null 2>&1
#set back to original volume
amixer -D pulse sset Master %30

gxmessage -fg blue -font  'sans 20' -timeout 2 ' Tea is ready. !!'
```

Comment: This should already be the default behaviour - trying to close it will warn that a command is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Depending on how you would display the text, this may or may not work for you. More generally though, this is a valid way to keep something running.*

You can use [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). You'll need to install it with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install tmux`.

Once installed, you can launch a tmux session by running `tmux` in a shell. Once in the session, you can run commands and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd> to hide the session. But, once hidden, even if you close the terminal, you can get back to your session by running `tmux a` from a shell. You can run `exit` from in the tmux session to, well, exit it.

This doesn't *actually* prevent it from being closed. But, it keeps it running even if you close the terminal window, so that may be sufficient for your use case.

Comment: I am trying to make things simpler. Can I run my script from tmux?

Comment: FYI, another way to keep it running in the background is to run `command & disown` where "command" is whatever command you want to run. This has slightly less overhead than using tmux or screen.

Answer (score 6):

You can run your script as a daemon using the [`daemon`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/daemon.1.html) command, which runs the script in the background :

```
daemon --name="yourservicename" --output=./yourlog.txt ./yourscript
```

To stop the daemon:

```
daemon --name="yourservicename" --stop
```

To install daemon:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install daemon
```

The only other thing you will need to do is modify your script to send your messages via `notify-send` (As mentioned in your question) :

`notify-send -u critical -t 0 "Meteor shower occurs after midnight."`

When you use `-u critical -t 0` options, The notification will stay on the screen until you click on it.

**Alternatively, you can use** `nohup`:

`nohup ./yourscript &`

You will still need to modify your script to send your messages via `notify-send` as described above.

Comment: Will you need to make the script executable and if it's not in a directory that is in your PATH, need to also use the full path to the script like `./yourscript` for example, if the script is in the current directory?

Comment: I am 68 years old. My memory is lacking.                                                                          Your answer looks good, but  I have a hard time doing more than 2 or 3 steps. Having chronic pain does not help.

Comment: @mchid I answered the question from the standpoint the OP already has a running script, I added your PATH suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @fixit7 I updated my answer and provided a simpler solution. I hope you find it acceptable. If not, you can [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1491672/edit) your question to include the script you are running. I would be happy to edit it and include it in my answer.

Comment: @mchid In general, it's not necessary to make a script executable in order to run it. You can run it using its interpreter, e.g. if it's a bash script, you can run `bash yourscript`. (And in that case it's not necessary to prepend `./` to the filename, although you generally do still have to give a valid relative or absolute path to the script file.)

Comment: @fixit7 Using `nohup` in answer I provided works fine (without any script modification), Only if you use the correct syntax defined in the script you provided in your question. E.g. `nohup ./yourscript 5m "Water is boiling" &`  You will need to ask a [New Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) if you want your script to work with `nohup` and do command syntax checking. BTW your current script will not display your custom message. Consider changing the line in your script to `gxmessage -fg blue -font  'sans 20' -timeout 2 "$2"`